# Controlling input number field min/max

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, range, limit

I have these two input fields that represent a range of time (seconds), and I need to make it so the "from/min" field can't go higher than the "to/max" and viceversa.

So far I got this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
 jQuery('#from').on( 'input', function( ) {
   if( parseInt( jQuery('#from').val() ) >= parseInt( jQuery('#to').val() ) ) jQuery('#from').val( parseInt( jQuery('#from').val() ) - 1 );
 });
  
 jQuery('#to').on( 'input', function( ) {
   if( parseInt( jQuery('#to').val() ) <= parseInt( jQuery('#from').val() ) ) jQuery('#to').val( parseInt( jQuery('#to').val() ) + 1 );
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
From: <input type="number" min="10" step="1" id="from" value="60"><br />
To: <input type="number" min="11" step="1" id="to" value="120">
```

It works fine when using the field or keyboard arrows, but I can still type any number/+/- on it and go lower/higher than the other field.

I am using:

```
jQuery('#from, #to').on( 'keypress', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

to prevent typing as a workaround at the moment, but I'd like to be able to type a number in while still keeping the limitation of not being able to go lower/higher than the other field

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call `preventDefault` when its match your condition to prevent it for keep (for example) increasing the value. Here, I bind to jQuery custom `input` event instead to make it also listen to `paste` event.

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
  $('#from').on('input', function (e) {
    var from = parseInt($(this).val(), 10)
    var to = parseInt($('#to').val(), 10)

    if (from >= to) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).val(to -1)
    }
  })
  
  $('#to').on('input', function (e) {
    var from = parseInt($('#from').val(), 10)
    var to = parseInt($(this).val(), 10)
    
    if (to <= from) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).val(from + 1)
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
From: <input type="number" min="10" step="1" id="from" value="60"><br />
To: <input type="number" min="11" step="1" id="to" value="120">
```

Comment: Works great, still have to modify it to prevent typing +/- and empty values. But your code is exactly what I need, thanks a lot.